# Should I capitalize this?

Tags: capitalization, quotations

Usually, "Yes," "No," and "Leave me alone" were the only utterances anyone could get out of me.

Should yes, no, and leave be capitalized here?

thanks

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: You're quoting full sentences, so you capitalize the first letter.

Comment: The commas within the quote-marks seem out-of-place to me.

Comment: I agree, but Americans have a convention where commas and periods are always inside quotes, regardless of context. I'd ask which English conventions the OP's using, but the commas are off topic.